# Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I want to convert a React component to be typed and I have got this typescript error
when I assign `setCharacters(arrayOfObj);`

```
export type CharacterItem = {
    filepath: string;
    group: string;
    id: string;
    isClicked: boolean;
   }

export type Character = {
    name: string;
   items: CharacterItem[]
   }
xxxxxx
  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([]);
xxxxxx
setCharacters(arrayOfObj); # the error is here
```

so a lint error is highlighted underneath `arrayOfObj` saying

```
const arrayOfObj: unknown[]
Argument of type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using it wrong I guess. Character type is not an array already and also your useState hook does not use your type as well. This may fix it:

```
 export type Character = {
    name: string;
   items: CharacterItem[]
   }[]

  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState<Character>([]);
```

Comment: I would not alter the `Character` type, but use `useState<Character[]>([])` instead.

Comment: Yes that would be better I guess :)